# How to create CDKTF script in golang for creating Kubernetes Namespaces

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-cdk

I have Terraform script for creating Kubernetes namespaces, but can not find the import statement for package in golang which would do the same job in CKDTF for go lang.

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "stage-namespace-1" {
  depends_on = [google_container_cluster.primary]
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "example-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "label-value"
    }

    name = "stage-namespace-1"
  }
}
```

I am using this package for creating other resources

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    ...
    "github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-google-go/google/v5/computeinstance"
    "github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-google-go/google/v5/computenetwork"
    "github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-google-go/google/v5/computesubnetwork"
    "github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-google-go/google/v5/containercluster"
    "github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-google-go/google/v5/provider"
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the pre-built kubernetes provider: https://github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-kubernetes-go. You can do this by running `cdktf provider add kubernetes`.

In import statement it can be used on this way

```
import (
...
kubernetesprovider "github.com/cdktf/cdktf-provider-kubernetes-go/kubernetes/v5/provider"
....
)
```

`kubernetesprovider` is used as alias to avoid conflicts with google or aws provider